# Adding a UV-map material in Unity 5 not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, uv-mapping

I am currently using Unity 5 to setup a small game so that I can see the assets I recently made in blender in action.

I have created a uv-map in blender and added the necessary colour (it works and displays nicely and blender) but it doesn't seem to work in Unity. What I've done is created a material, chosen the uv (under the albedo option) and then applied it in the skinned-mesh renderer of the object but it colours the entire object only one of the colours included or it just doesn't colour at all. I tried messing with the import options (swapping the UV's) but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a chance you've been tricked by the annoying new button in Unity's "new" shader,

To change the :actual texture", it's called `Albedo` which is annoying.

You must click precisely the little "dot" shown below!

The "little dot" is between the small square, and the word "Albedo".

Then, a selector panel appears. ***HOWEVER*** there is a soft bug: When the selector panel appears **it immediately goes to the back of all windows**.

Many people, certainly myself, get fooled by this. It's quite annoying.

[image]

So, hopefully the problem is just that you have not yet selected the texture to display, considering the "tricky button issue" on Unity's "new" universal shader.

Comment: That is so freaking annoying. I'm sure I've done that several times but it never worked. Thanks though.

Comment: My pleasure, good question.  I wish this had been asked before on here, would have saved me time!!

Comment: Actually, the problem still exists although I've figured out what the issue now. I'll make a separate post.